# Proof that $\lim_{s\to 1}\ln \zeta (s)$ diverges

Tags: calculus, limits, analysis, riemann-zeta

I'm trying to prove that
$$\displaystyle\lim_{s\to 1}\ln\zeta (s) \,\text{diverges}. \tag*{(*)}$$
Initially, I thought of
$$\displaystyle\lim_{s\to 1}\ln\zeta (s)=\ln\displaystyle\lim_{s\to 1}\zeta (s)\implies \left(\displaystyle\lim_{s\to 1}\ln \zeta (s) \,\text{converges}\,\iff \ln\lim_{s\to 1}\zeta (s)\,\text{converges}\right).$$
But then we have that it's not always true that
$$\displaystyle\lim_{s\to a}\ln f(s)=\ln \displaystyle\lim_{s\to a} f(s),$$
so I ruled the "proof" out. How can I prove $(*)$?

Comment: Is it the real or the complex $\zeta$? Which logarithm? Where may $s$ not come from? Because there exists a holomorphic $h$ in a neighborhood of $1$, such that, in said neighborhood, $\zeta(s)=\frac{e^{h(s)}}{s-1}$ and $\ln{s-1}$ is undefined in a neighborhood of $1$.

Comment: @Mindlack $\zeta (s)=\prod_{p\in\mathbb P}\frac{1}{1-p^{-s}}$ where $\operatorname{Re}s\gt 1$. Regarding the natural log: $\ln \zeta (s)=\sum_{p\in \mathbb P}\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{p^{-ns}}{n}$ where $\operatorname{Re}s\gt 1$.

Comment: It's not hard to show that $\zeta(x) > 1/(x-1)$ for real $x>1$ (see for example Section 1.3 of Montgomery/Vaughan's book). Doesn't this imply the nonexistence of your limit?

Comment: If you mean $\lim_{s \to 1^+} \ln \zeta(s)$ then it is obvious it is $= +\infty$ from $\zeta(s)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty n^{-s}$. If you mean $\lim_{s \to 1,\Re(s)>1} \log \zeta(s)$ or $\lim_{s \to 1} \log \zeta(s)$ then you'll need to show first that $\zeta(s)(s-1)$ is analytic and non-zero at $s=1$.

Comment: @reuns Thanks. And how would I go about $\lim_{s\to 1}|\ln \zeta (s)|$? Is it needed to prove the analyticity even though $|\ln \zeta (s)|$ is real?

Comment: Do you understand the difference between $\lim_{s \to 1, s > 1}$ and $\lim_{s \to 1, s \in \Bbb{C}}$ ???

Comment: @reuns Yes. Also, regarding your preceding comment, you state it's obvious that $\lim_{s\to 1^+}\ln\zeta (s)$ diverges — it's because $\lim_{s\to 1^+}\sum_{n=1}^\infty n^{-s}$ diverges. But how can we use $\lim_{s\to a}\ln f(s)=\ln \lim_{s\to a}f(s)$ when $\ln$ is not continuous at $f(a)$?

Comment: why do you think $\ln$ isn't "continuous at $+\infty$"

Comment: @reuns If we use $\ln$ in the projectively extended real line, then $\ln$ is continuous at $\infty$, but in the case of reals, $\ln$ is not continuous at $\infty$. It seems this is just a matter of the definition of the domain of $\ln$.

Comment: If "$f$ is continuous at $a$" means $a_n \to a \implies f(a_n) \to f(a)$ then $f(x) = \ln x,x >0$ is continuous at $+\infty$ and $0$. No need to extend the real line, the definition of $a_n \to + \infty$ is all we need.